# docker- compose error: service 'build' must be a mapper not a string error

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I already tried to solve this problem by looking other people's similar errors here in Stackoverflow but nothing works for me:
I keep getting that error. Here's my docker-compose.yml file:

```
identidock:

build:
.
ports:
- "5000:5000"
environment:
 ENV: DEV
volumes ./app:app
```

Comment: The indentation in your YAML file looks off. Please check if you've inserted it correctly in your question

Comment: Does indentation matter in YAML files?